# Permission denied when writing file from PAM module

Tags: linux, file-io, centos, permission-denied, pam

I am trying to write a PAM module that logs information about authentication attempts from SSH into a file.

I have written a module that gets loaded by OpenSSH and then gets called on authentication attempts. The module is based on this code: http://www.adeptus-mechanicus.com/codex/logsshp/logsshp.html.

However, the problem is that whenever I try to write my log, my code always fails to open the log file: it returns errno 13, "Permission denied".

I have tried writing to "/var/log/auth_ssh_attempts.log", "/var/log/auth_ssh_attempts" and into a file in my home directory. None of these locations allow me to open the file. I am not sure what is wrong with my approach here.

I even tried calling setuid(0) at the start of the function, which is returning successfully. So I am at a loss as to why I am not allowed to write into /var/log.

This is on CentOS 6.5.

Any help on this issue would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Usually when one hits the "Permission denied" problem in Linux, it is due to that the file you are trying to modify is not owned by the user trying to write to it or at least that user does not have the right permissions to write to the file. Try `chmod 777 <file>` on the file you want to write to to see if works. After that you might consider lowering the permission to something more safe. As a side-note, when posting similar problems, try to include the output of the current permissions of your files. That would be done with `ls -la` in the directory of the file(s) you're trying to write to.

Comment: @mattias Thank you for the comment .Initially the file did not exist (I was opening the file with O_CREAT). However, I tried it after creating the file and calling chmod 777 on it and it still would not work (still error 13, permission denied).

I am also confused why root would not be allowed to create a file in /var/log in the first place? I will post the output of ls -al when I get home.

Comment: Not to make this a long drawn-out discussion thread but, was the problem solved? I am still quite sure this error you experienced has to do with permissions.

Comment: @mattias, sorry for taking so long to respond. I figured out I could make the module write to /tmp, which was good enough for my purposes at the time (though writing into /var/log/ is preferable in the future). I then got siderailed by a few other projects. I don't think UNIX file permissions were the problem in this case (because even with permissions set to 777 I couldn't write). However, I am now fairly convinced it was SELinux that was causing issues. I will test this later today by disabling SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this exact same issue on CentOS 7 - could write to a file in /tmp folder, but continuously got Errno 13 when trying to write to a file within /var/log directory.
Turns out my issue as because of SELinux blocking my access - https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

If you disable it and reboot your computer it should fix the issue -
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/